# Small problem on minus sign $({-5}+{9}x)y'={4}x+{9}y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I have the equation $$({-5}+{9}x)y'={4}x+{9}y$$

So I am trying to solve it in the way need to solve linear differential equation.

I recognise that I can write it as : $$({-5}+{9}x)y' -{9}y={4}x$$

now I dont know what I should do, I know that I could write $(({-5}+{9}x)y)^\prime=\int4xdx$

if just my expression was different by minus sign. so what is the thechnique in such problems? this is not the first time I getting in a situation like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of the integrating factor?  Divide the equation by $9x-5$ and change the minus sign to a plus sign by distributing $-1$ to the $9x-5$ when you divide $9y$ by it:
$$y'+\frac{9}{5-9x} y=\frac{4x}{9x-5}$$
Then this is just a standard integrating factor problem.
Multiply both sides of the equation by:
$$exp\left(\int \frac{9}{5-9x} \; dx \right)= \frac{1}{5-9x}$$
$$\left(\frac{y}{5-9x}\right)'=\frac{-4x}{(9x-5)^2}$$
Lastly, integrate both sides and don't forget the constant.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: divide both sides by $-5+9x$, and rewrite the ODE in the form: $y’ + Py = Q$, and use the 1st ODE formula to proceed .

Answer (score 0):

$$({-5}+{9}x)y' -{9}y={4}x$$
No you can't write this:
$$(({-5}+{9}x)y)^\prime=4x$$
Since $(fg)'=f'g \color {red}{+}fg'$ but you can try to have something like:
$$\left ( \dfrac f g\right)'=\dfrac {f'g\color {red}{-}fg'}{g^2}$$
$$\left ( \dfrac y {9x-5}\right)'= \dfrac {4x}{(9x-5)^2}$$
And integrate both sides.